# React using variable in multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a product component that has an add to cart button, when I click add to cart it adds the product to the basket and totals up the cost of the basket, how do I use the `totalCost` and `nameArr` variables within a different component?

I want to be able to create a basket component that passes in the `nameArr` variable to show which items a user has in their basket and the the `totalCost` variable to show the user how much they have to pay

What is the best way to achieve this?

How would I achieve this

```
var nameArr = []; 
var costStr = ""; 
var costArr = []; 
var totalCost = 0;
export default function Product(props) {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    totalCost = 0;
    nameArr.push(`${props.name}`);
    costStr += `${props.price}, `;
    costArr = costStr.split`,`.map((x) => +x);
    for (var i = 0; i < costArr.length; i++) {
      totalCost += costArr[i];
    }   
    console.log(
            `${props.name} added to basket at price of £${props.price}\nbasket: ${nameArr}\ntotal: £${totalCost}`
    );  
  };  
  return (
    <div className={styles.product}>
      <Link href={props.link}>
        <img src={props.img} alt={props.name} />
      </Link>
      <Link href={props.link}>
        <h3>{props.name}</h3>
      </Link>
      <span>{props.price}</span>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add to Bag</button>
    </div>
  );  
}
```

Comment: I would read up on [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), it's a built-in API for sharing data between components. You can store the shared data in a context and provide methods to update it, then pass it down to all components that use it. There are other solutions like Redux or other Flux implementations, but it's not particularly suited to smaller projects.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use some sort of state management tool like Redux, but if that is a bit overkill for this project, you can always pass function as props to other component and change the state outside of the component. The official ReactJS website has some really good docs on this, I suggest you read it thoroughly and learn to implement this on your own.

Lifting State Up in React:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

If you use function as components then you can use hooks to update the state: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a new file with those variables and just refer to it in every component you need.